# How to get a session uid to allow access to page

Tags: php, session

I am trying to get a certain uid number to access page if they are not in db then it redirects them to index page. Here is the code I put on top of the page. I keep getting an error this does not seem correct.

```
 <?php 
        session_start();

        if(!isset($_SESSION['uid'] = 12 )){
        header('Location:index.php');
        }
     ?>
```

Comment: What is the error? And your if statement is incorrect - you need "=="

Comment: `if(!isset($_SESSION['uid'] = 12 ))` that doesn't do what you hope it would.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to seperate this into two parts.

```
<?php

        session_start();

        if(!isset($_SESSION['uid']) || $_SESSION['uid'] != 12){
            header('Location:index.php');
            exit;
        }

?>
```